Storing API Keys in a secure and runtime editable way....?
I'm working on node project at the moment. My application communicates to the API of another application in order to get or upload data. Each request must have a key in order to be authenticated by the other server. Right now I am storing the API Key in a .env file. From my understanding .env files are not supposed to be edited by code.
I'm trying to find the best way to securely store an API Key such that it can be changed during runtime if necessary.
Any thoughts?

Sounds like you might be looking for a secrets manager. Many secrets managers allow you to edit your API Keys (or other secrets) from a dashboard and then trigger an automatic restart to pick up the new keys when they change (like the --watch flag for the Doppler CLI).
As a bonus, if your keys are ever leaked, at risk, or just changed, you can rotate them all in one place, and the rest is automatic. No need to go into every instance of your application and manually rotate keys.
